# PostgreSQL table rotation and following query handling

Tags: postgresql, rotation

Is there a way to define e table rotation based (for example) on a date field in table divided per month or per year? after that is there a way to centralize the query on a single point and then make automatically union of all results coming from all tables. 
Just to be clear, if i call "SELECT * FROM TABLE" i would like to get all data from all rotation tables.
Is this possible?

Comment: Are you talking about table partitioning?

Comment: yes, i think i found something using inherits and trigger on main table

Comment: What PG version are you using?

Comment: PostgreSQL 9.5.10

Comment: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/ddl-partitioning.html